# Number of ways to arrange 5 indistinguishable balls in 12 boxes so that no two are next to each other

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have two ways of doing this question but they give different answers. The reasoning in one of my methods must be flawed and I would appreciate any help in pointing it out.

Method 1.
First assume balls are distinguishable then divide by 5! at the end.

Number of ways to arrange 5 balls with no constraint is $12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8 $

Number of ways to arrange 5 balls with at least 1 ball next to each other is $$ 10\cdot2\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8+2\cdot1\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8$$

The first part comes from putting the first ball in 1 of the 10 middle boxes then putting the second ball in one of the boxes next to it and putting the remaining 3 balls anywhere.

The second part comes from putting the first ball in one of the the two end boxes, then putting the second ball next to it and the remaining 3 anywhere.

and the final answer is

$$ \frac{12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8-(10\cdot2\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8+2\cdot1\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8)}{5!}$$

I strongly believe this method is flawed, can someone help me point out where I went wrong.

The other method which I assume to be correct is.

$$\binom{6}{5}+2\cdot\binom{6}{4}+\binom{6}{3}$$

This one comes from arranging the blue balls in between gaps.

Comment: I think you have problems with double counting.  Suppose you put two balls in the middle and then $3$ elsewhere.  If the "elsewhere" includes two balls on the end, you will also count this arrangement in your next group.

Comment: @saulspatz Ah I see, is there a way to fix this. Nevertheless, if I double counted, then the numerator should be much smaller than the actual number, but the answer from that method is greater than the answer for the second method.

Comment: One way of dealing with double counting is by the use on [inclusion and exclusion].    It's a bit complicated in this case, because you have to consider various ways of getting more than one pair.  For example if you have 123 and 78 that counts as three pairs.  I don't understand how you got your second answer.  What are the blue balls?  What are the gaps?

Comment: @saulspatz. For the second answer, for the first term, assume that the first and last box are empty, there 7 empty boxes and 6 gaps between them, we have to fill 5 of those 6 gaps with balls, so 6 choose 5. For the second term assume 1 box at the end has a blue ball, now we still have 7 empty boxes and 6 gaps but we only have to distribute 4 balls. And the last term comes from putting a blue ball at both ends.

Comment: @saulspatz For the first method I basically wanted to do something like. Number of ways unconstrained - number of ways with at least 1 pair next to each other. Do you know how to calculate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You second calculation is correct.  To do it the first way, you can use the [principle of inclusion and exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), as I said.  There are $12 \choose5$ ways to distribute $5$ balls.  There are $11$ ways to place two balls next to one another, and then $10\choose3$ ways to distribute the remaining balls giving $${12 \choose5}-11\cdot{10\choose3}$$ ways so far. However, we have subtracted any distribution with two pairs of consecutive balls twice, so we have to add those back in.  This is a bit tricky, since we could either have two pairs that don't touch, or a run of three.  Once you've figured that out, you need to subtract out the distributions with three pairs.  This can either be a pair and run of three or a run of four.  Finally, you need to add back the distributions with four pairs, which can only be a run of five.